# I want to set validation to my subscriber form PHP HTML what do i need to add?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

My Form HTML

```
<p><span>Enter Name: </span><input type="text" name="Name" size="20"></p>
<p><span>Enter Email: </span><input type="text" name="Email" size="20"></p>
<p> Enter DOB: <input type="text" name="Dob" size="20"></p>
<p ><span><input type="submit" value="Save Data" name="Submit"></span></p>
```

My PHP Side for form

```
if(isset($_POST['Name']) && isset($_POST['Email']) && isset($_POST['Dob']))     {
$data = $_POST['Name'] . '-' . $_POST['Email'] . '-' . $_POST['Dob'] . "\n";
$ret = file_put_contents('mydata.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
if($ret === false) {
    die('There was an error writing this file');
}
else {
    echo "$ret bytes written to file";
}
}
else {
   die('no post data to process');
}

$location = "success.html";
header( "Location: $location" );
```

The form is working and doing as it should but I want to validate that:
Name is only alphabet
Email is correct format @ ect
DOB is numbers

Thanks for anyone who can help

Comment: simplest way put required in input like `<input type="text" name="Name" size="20" required />` for more detail check use jQuery validation plugin

Comment: What would adding required do? it wouldnt know what is required ect?

Comment: required just only do this > if input blank it will not let the user submit the form unless they put something in it but it will not validate its correctly formatted email or dob is in number, so thats why i sugesst jQuery validation plugin, you can google it and it has easy examples which can be integrated in no time and will do exactly you are asking

Comment: for email: `if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
//valid}`

Comment: I have trierd jquery and it just got me in circles  -.-

Answer (score 0):

Your validation can be done in two steps:

1. Validate content in UI before form is submitted.
   This staff is not really safe, but can avoid too many user wrong inputs by defining rules with javascript.
2. Validated post content when POST is arrived to php.
   Use this function

   ```
   function email($email){
   /*
    * Checks mail by preg_match
    */
   if(!preg_match('/^[_A-z0-9-]+((\.|\+)[_A-z0-9-]+)*@[A-z0-9-]+(\.[A-z0-9-]+)*(\.[A-z]{2,4})$/',$email)){
       return false;
   } else {
       return true;
   }
   ```

   }